# Training Convolutional Autoencoder with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm training a convolutional autoencoder for IR faces, this is my first time doing autoencoder. I have about 1300 training images, and I didn't using any regulation method. Here's what I got after 800 epochs:
[top: test images, bottom: output from autoencoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk3Ji.jpg).

And this is my training curve: [top: training loss, bottom: validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fppcV.jpg). Validation loss uses the test set images that is separated from training set. At the end, the training loss is about 0.006, but the validation loss is 0.009.

My model is defined bellow, with input images with size 110X150 and output images with size 88X120. I simply resize the source images to make the training labels. Each sample/label are normalized by dividing by 255. 
As for the architecture of this network, I read one paper using this similar layout for RGB images face feature, and I halved each layer's depth (channels) for my purpose.

So my question is, is there something wrong? The training curve is quite weird to me. And how do I improve this autoencoder? More epochs? Regulations? Choose another activation function(I heard about leaky ReLU is better). Any feedback and suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

```html
def create_models():
 input_img = Input(shape=(150, 110, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

 x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
 x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
 x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
 x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
 x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
 x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
 x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
 encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)


 # at this point the representation is (8, 6, 512) i.e. 128-dimensional
 x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
 x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
 x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
 x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
 x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
 x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
 x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
 x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
 decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)

 autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)


 autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error')
 return autoencoder
```